# Не распознаётся путь к файлу

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyttsx3

Пишу программу для преобразования текста в речь. столкнулся с проблемой когда не распознаётся путь к файлу текста.

```py
import pyttsx3
from gtts import gTTS

work = pyttsx3.init()
file = open("C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Текст_в_аудио.txt", 'r')
Text = file.read()

work.say(Text)
work.runAndWait()
file.close()

tts = gTTS(text=Text, lang='uk')
tts.save('Text_in_audio.mp3')

print('File saved!')
```

По итогу имею ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**В чем проблема?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что последовательности, типа `\U` воспринимаются как один спец. символ, а не как 2 разных символа. Как исправить: `open(r"C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Текст_в_аудио.txt", 'r')`.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте специальные модули:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

path1 = os.path.join("C:", os.sep, "Users", "Home", "Desktop", "Текст_в_аудио.txt")
path2 = Path('C:', '/', "Users", "Home", "Desktop", "Текст_в_аудио.txt")

print(path1)
print(path2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mport pyttsx3
from gtts import gTTS

work = pyttsx3.init()
file = open(r"C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Текст_в_аудио.txt", 'r')
Text = file.read()

work.say(Text)
work.runAndWait()
file.close()

tts = gTTS(text=Text, lang='uk')
tts.save('Text_in_audio.mp3')

print('File saved!')
```